# MySQL Performance issue: select query takes forever

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, optimization

This is vitally important query of the project that calculates statistic information for each user, generates almost 300k rows but it takes forever to get answer.

The problem is, this query is needed to be executed almost every 20-30 seconds and the row count always grows.

Despite the fact that the fields that used in join and where are indexed it takes around 2000 seconds to get the answer from query.

One another fact is, the tables used in this query are large. For example, IconKeyword holds almost 95M records.

Please take a look and tell me how can I optimize this query

```
SELECT
    Icon.`user_id` AS user_id,
    Keyword.`id` AS keyword_id,
    Keyword.`title` AS keyword_title,
    Keyword.`demand` AS keyword_demand,
    count( IconKeyword.`iconID` ) AS ico_count,
    Icon.`type` AS icon_type,
    Keyword.`common` AS common 
    FROM
        Icon
        INNER JOIN IconKeyword ON IconKeyword.iconID = Icon.id
        INNER JOIN Keyword ON Keyword.id = IconKeyword.keywordID 
    WHERE
        Keyword.is_deleted = 0 
        AND
        Keyword.restricted = 0 
    GROUP BY
        Icon.`user_id`,
        Icon.type,
        Keyword.id;
```

And here is explain results:
[image]

Create tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `Icon` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `uri` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
  `type` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `f_id` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `color` tinyint unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `pack_id` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `pack_bg` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `fi_url` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_deleted` tinyint unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `count_of_sets` int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p_hash` binary(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hash_bit_count` int unsigned GENERATED ALWAYS AS (bit_count(`p_hash`)) STORED,
  `checked` tinyint unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `md5` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `f_id` (`f_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `id` (`id`,`type`,`user_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `type` (`type`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `uri` (`uri`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `hash_bit_count` (`hash_bit_count`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `is_deleted` (`is_deleted`),
  KEY `checked` (`checked`),
  KEY `user_id_2` (`user_id`,`type`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `Icon_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `User` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=118691 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `Keyword` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `common` tinyint unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `demand` int DEFAULT '0',
  `f_id` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_deleted` tinyint unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `needs_review` tinyint unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `checked` tinyint unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `restricted` tinyint unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `word_checked` tinyint unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `slug` (`slug`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `title` (`title`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `is_deleted` (`is_deleted`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `restricted` (`restricted`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `restricted_2` (`restricted`,`is_deleted`,`id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=30000392 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `IconKeyword` (
  `iconID` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `keywordID` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`iconID`,`keywordID`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `keywordID_2` (`keywordID`,`iconID`),
  KEY `keywordID` (`keywordID`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `iconID` (`iconID`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `ik_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`keywordID`) REFERENCES `Keyword` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `ik_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`iconID`) REFERENCES `Icon` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Hmmm... Why two hashes and two unique keys and two URLs in `Icon`?

Comment: @RickJames it's a different story: p_hash is photo_hash to check similarity. but think these questions has nothing to do the problem, right?

Comment: How many rows in the result set?  My question about "two of ..." is just for understanding whether this is simply a many-to-many relation between two entities (icons and keywords) or something more complex.

Comment: Perhaps user_id + type is unique?

Comment: @RickJames user_id + type is not unique. No icon type is like: filled, outline .. etc. general type of icon. In results of the function almost 300K.

Comment: @RickJames IconKeyword has almost 93M rows and many to many

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211981/discussion-between-demonoid-and-rick-james).

Answer (score 1):

For your query, you can try adding indexes on:

- `keyword(is_deleted, is_restricted, id)`
- `IconKeyword(KeywordId, IconId)`
- `Icon(id)`  (which should already exist because `id` is a primary key)

The query will still need to do a lot of work for the aggregation, but this might help.

Comment: do you mean to index these fields separately or together?

Comment: IconKeyword - (KeywordId, IconId) is unique combination so that means they are indexed, added to Keyword this trio as an index, Icon's id is PK so it's indexed

Comment: @demonoid  . . . This describes three indexes, with 3, 2, and 1 column each, respectively.  The last is probably not needed if `id` is already declared as the primary key.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the number of records that have `Keyword.is_deleted = 0 AND Keyword.restricted = 0` is quite large, so adding indexes here wouldn't help much.

What you can try is helping the aggregation works faster by adding a [Multiple-Column Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html), specifically `(Icon.user_id, Icon.type)` because it's what you're using in `GROUP BY`

Also, can you provide an `EXPLAIN` result of this query so we can better understand what is causing the performance problem.

Comment: provided explain in question by your request

Comment: Since the `GROUP BY` involves two different tables, no index can help.